# How to run survey weights in R?

Tags: r, spss

I'm keen to learn how to correctly apply survey weights in R. I tried to multiply the variable to create a new one but I didn't get anything intelligible out e.g.:

```
data2019$income_weighted <- data2019$income*data2019$population_weight
```

Here is the code in SPSS that I would usually run:

```
FREQUENCIES income.

WEIGHT BY population_weight.
```

FREQUENCIES income.

Grateful for any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the `survey` package in `R`. This is probably the most complete package regarding survey designs. You can find some elements in `questionr` package.

You can find some functions to compute summary statistics with weighted data in `Hmisc` package, e.g. `Hmisc::wtd.quantile`. If your survey design is complex, I would strongly encourage you to favor the `survey` package. Otherwise, the functions from `Hmisc` might be enough to start with

Regarding your example `Hmisc` does the job:

```r
data2019$income_weighted <- Hmisc::wtd.mean(data2019$income, weights = data2019$population_weight)
```